# K-nearest neighbor model with gaussian distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics, gaussian

Assume that I have 3 different classes which follow a Gaussian distribution generated in the following way:

```
x1 = np.random.random((100,7))
x2 = np.random.random((200,7))
x3 = np.random.random((300,7))

mean_x1 = np.mean(x1, axis = 0)
mean_x2 = np.mean(x2, axis = 0)
mean_x3 = np.mean(x3, axis = 0)

cov_x1 = np.cov(x1.T)
cov_x2 = np.cov(x2.T)
cov_x3 = np.cov(x3.T)

Class_1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_x1, cov_x1, 100)
Class_2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_x2, cov_x2, 200)
Class_3 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_x3, cov_x3, 300)
```

And that I would like to perform a classification task based on KNN model to predict the Class of a test sample which also follows a Gaussian distribution, i.e., if it is Class_1, Class_2 or Class_3 based on their mean values.

Can someone provide me with an explanation on how to do it?

Comment: So, in short, you want to make KNN classification on a toy dataset generated using multivariate normal distribution? BTW, I think you can sample directly your mean vector instead of taking the mean of randomly generated vectors.

Comment: Hello LucG, thank you for your reply. Yes that's exactly the aim and as you said, I can sample the mean vector manually but I prefered to get it randomly. Please tell me if I did something wrong with it.

Comment: You can get your mean vectors randomly by just doing `mean_x =np.random.random((7,))`. The effect would be the same. Concerning your KNN question, I don't think it is fit for stackoverflow as being too broad. I suggest you go read this page here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbors-classification . Which contains an example for KNN classification. It is a good start.

Comment: Thank you LucG. I will refer to it.